# Python not loading a specific function

Tags: python, import, module

I just run into a problem with the `hamster`'s codebase where a module is loaded with one function and not the other. It's not my code, so I don't know many details, but I'd really like to learn how can such situation arise.

There is a module called `hamster` which includes `i18n.py` which has two functions: `setup_i18n` and `C_`. There is no `__all__` defined in `__init__`. After loading the module `C_` is visible, but the setup function isn't.

Here's the link for i18n file and the repo in general: http://git.gnome.org/browse/hamster-applet/tree/src/hamster/i18n.py?id=94b8ba72dad5b3e711d5f6b6a7018d83d770ce14

The session is only this (after setting the correct `sys.path` to include the packages)

```
> from hamster import i18n
> dir(i18n)
['C_', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', 'gettext']
```

Comment: What actual problem do you have?  Does something not work?  If it doesn't work, please post the code which does not work and the error message showing exactly what is not working.  The code you showed is correct and works.  It's expected.  Please post your **error** or your **problem**.

Comment: @S.Lott Not sure what you expect here. I posted the session which shows the problem. I expect `setup_i18n` in the output of `dir(i18n)`, since it's defined in the file - and I want to know could cause it to not be there.

Comment: I have lots of unmet expectations.  I don't see how a missing name from a `dir()` breaks anything or leads to any problems.  The question is incomplete.  You expected a name which is not there.  So?  What's broken?  What error are you getting?  What's the problem?  Inexperienced Python programmers who find this question need to know *why* this is important and what problem you have and how the answer will solve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an old version of the file in your system path.  Notice that the most recent change to that file in the repo is to add the `setup_i18n` function.  It's also possible you have an old .pyc file that for some reason isn't being compared properly to the .py file.

Comment: I cloned the git repo and was about to post an answer saying I couldn't repro this problem (after not finding anything browsing source that would give this behavior), but you've beat me to the punch and explained why too.

Comment: That was the case - there was a stale `.pyc` which was not updated even though `.py` changed. Thanks.